Yolov8 inference working on Mac but not Windows
I am using Yolo v8 from ultralytics inside pycharm to run inference on a model I trained, when I run it on a macbook it works fine but on my windows laptop, I get tons of bounding boxes everywhere with confidence scores of 1 even though I am using the same best.pt file and the same code:
an example of what is happening
from ultralytics import YOLO
from ultralytics.utils.benchmarks import benchmark

model = YOLO("best.pt")
# model = YOLO("yolov8m.pt")

results = model(source=0, show=True, conf=0.6, save=True)
# results = model.track(source=0, show=True, conf=0.6, tracker="bytetrack.yaml")

I also previously had an issue similar (not the same) to this one linked below where pytorch wasn't detected by pycharm and I got an error each time I imported it:
import torch: How to fix OSError WinError 126, error loading fbgemm.dll or dependencies
I fixed it using the libomp140.x86_64.dll file a user gave and putting it in C:\Windows\System32, could this be the problem?
What I have already tried:
I tried to re-install the ultralytics and pytorch libraries and pycharm, thinking it was a problem with their installation, but nothing changed.
Edit: The issue was solved by downgrading ultralytics version to 8.2.60 thanks to Christoph Rackwitz who pointed out that it was similar to this post:
Alot of incorrect detection using YOLOv8
It might also work by downgrading torch version, I will be sure to check the github for known issues next time.

welcome. please take the [tour]. questions should not contain "the answer". the usual way to deal with duplicate questions is to close them as duplicates. this is the appropriate way to model the situation. this helps search engines.
